# SQL ADDNOT WORKING

Tags: php, mysql, sql, odbc, addition

I'm trying to add a new record into my `database` using `SQl` and `PHP` with an `ODBC connection`. When I complete the form and click 'add', nothing happens! Here is my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['add'])){

    $conn=odbc_connect($data_source,$user,$password);   

    $Address1 = $_POST['Address1'];
    $Address2 = $_POST['Address2'];
    $Address3 = $_POST['Address3'];
    $Address5 = $_POST['Address5'];

    $contactName = $_POST['contactName'];
    $pic = $_POST['pic'];
    $emailAddress = $_POST['emailAddress'];
    $number = $_POST['number'];

    $pname = $_POST['pname'];
    $type = $_POST['type'];

    $emailAddress = $_POST['storage'];
    $number = $_POST['allergen'];

    $phama = $_POST['phama'];
    $health = $_POST['health'];

    $qp = $_POST['qp'];
    $transport = $_POST['transport'];

    $qac = $_POST['qac'];
    $qad = $_POST['qad'];



    $stmt = "INSERT INTO dbo.tblVersions2 (QuoteNumber, Address1, Address2, Address3, Address4, ContactName, PositionInCompany, EmailAddress, TelephoneNumber, ProductName, TypeOfService, StorageConditions, AllergenInfo) VALUES(NULL, '$Address1', 
'$Address2', '$Address3', '$Address4', '$Address5', '$contactName', '$pic', '$emailAddress', '$number', '$pname', '$type', '$storage',
'$allergen')";

    $result = odbc_execute($conn, $stmt);



if($result){
    echo "New Product Added";

}

else {
    echo "Product not Added"; 

}
    }
?>
```

Please help me find out what's wrong, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If nothing happens, i would say that

```
if(isset($_POST['add']))
```

is false.

You got more values than columns in your query.
Also, use parameters: https://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/

Comment: I now have the else bit returned "Product Added" after clearing some errors up such as variable names, still not adding to the database though! Any ideas?

Comment: 'Product not added" *

Comment: Well, if odbc_execute obviously fails, you could try to fetch the error-info using http://php.net/manual/de/function.odbc-error.php